# How to check whether list inside list is empty in hibernate response

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using @oneToMany annotation in my application to fetch data from another table. There are two Entity classes TopArtists.java and Subscribe.java. Here is **TopArtists.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name="full_name")
private String fullName;

@Column(name="username")
private String uname;


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="subscriber_id")
private List<Subscribe> subs;  

//Getters and setters
```

Here is **Subscribe.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private long id;
//private String status;

@Column(name="subscribed_id")
private String subID;

@Column(name="subscriber_id")
private long subrID;

//Gettes and setters
```

Here i am fetching data from subscribe table on the basis of subscribed_id. Here is my **DAO** class

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<TopUsers> getTopArtists() throws Exception {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(TopUsers.class);
        cr.addOrder(Order.asc("rank"));
        List topArtists = cr.list();
        tx = session.getTransaction();
        session.beginTransaction();
        tx.commit();
        return topArtists;
    }
```

Here the result is coming into List topArtists. Now I want to check whether Subscribe table has data corresponding to subscribed_id or not so i want to check if the subscribe list inside topArtist list is empty or not because if list is empty then i want to set another value to my Subscribe variables. Please suggest me how can i do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **[iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)** to iterate the `List<TopUsers>` and check for the List of `List<Subscribe>` for each one, here's the code you need:

```
List<TopUsers> usersList = getTopArtists();

Iterator<TopUsers> iter = usersList.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    //Getb the iterated element
    TopUsers user = (TopUsers) iter.next();

    //Check for the subs 
    //use the getSubs() getter to get the list of subs
    if(user.getSubs().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No subs found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx bhai ..Your code is working but how can i change the variable value is list is not empty

Comment: you can use the setter of the subs list, to modify it `user.setSubs(list)`.

Comment: `list` is the new list of subscribes that you wnat to give to your user.

Comment: Actually i want to set value of subID variable to false if list is empty and true if list is not empty

Comment: Actually the subID is in the Subscribe class, so if there's no subcribes (list is empty) there's no object of type Subcribe so there will be no column subId. You acn add a boolena flag in your user class and set it to false if list of subs is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84671/discussion-between-nadeem-ahmed-and-chsdk).

Comment: i dont want subscribe list data i only want true or false. if list is empty then false and if list is not empty then true

Answer (score 1):

To check subscribe list is empty use the following code:

```
for(TopArtists artist : topArtists) {
    if(artist.getSubs.isEmpty()) {
        //List is empty.
    } else {
        //List is not empty.  
    }
}
```

You can also use for loop instead of for each loop as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < topArtists.size(); i++) {
    if(topArtists.get(i).getSubs.isEmpty()) {
        //List is empty.
    } else {
        //List is not empty.  
    }
}
```

Let's assume Subscribe list is not empty then we can access or modify the values as:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < topArtists.size(); i++) {
        if(topArtists.get(i).getSubs.isEmpty()) {
            //List is empty.
        } else {
            //To fetch the List of Subscribe
            List<Subscribe> subList = topArtists.get(i).getSubs();

            //Iteration on Subscribe List
            for(int j = 0; j < subList.size(); j++) {
                //Changing the value of subID
                subList.get(j).setSubID("Any String");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is getSubs here?

Comment: and for(TopArtists(what is this?) artist : topArtists) {

Comment: getSubs is the getter method for getting the Subscribe list and "for(TopArtists artist : topArtists)" is the for each loop to iterate the List<TopArtists>.

Comment: But i am getting one problem if the list is empty then i can set variable value in subscribe list but if list is not empty then i am unable to change the value in subscribe list